# Most Optimal Byte Level Producer Consumer implementation in Java

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I am looking for an optimal producer-consumer implementation in Java with the following aspects:

1. Producer reads from server1 socket, and writes to a shared buffer, as well as another server 2 socket:

   > Server1 -> Server2 + shared buffer
2. Consumer reads from a shared buffer, and writes to server3 socket:

   > Shared Buffer -> Server3
3. **Writes to shared buffer from Server 1 should be non-blocking** (i.e. if the buffer is full it should not block the communication with Server 2).

I have considered the following options:

1. Java NIO Pipe
2. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Byte>` queue
3. `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`
4. I assume buffer can have a pre-allocated memory to avoid dynamic memory allocation overhead? Or should that not be a concern? If so what would be a fast implementation.

What would be the fastest?

I have already tried out `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`. My overhead compared to just forwarding data from server1->server2 was more than 12% this seemed excessive, which is why I came up with more options.

The specific part of the code already implemented, which is in the critical region (pertains to performance) is as follows in `CommunicateToServerAndPipe`:

```
 public void run() {
        try {
            String line = null;

            final byte[] request = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            //read from server 1 socket
            while (isRunning && (bytesRead = in.read(request)) != -1) {
                //write to server 2 socket
                out.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
                out.flush();
                //write to shared buffer pipe
                this.register.pos.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
            }
     register.kill();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if(ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            // The socket simply timed out. Kill, then exit.
            register.kill();
            return;
        }
        this.kill();
    }
}
```

I have made my initial code available [here](https://github.com/nipunarora/JavaTCPReplicationProxy).

Comment: If you are currently looking for the "most optimal" option, this means that you have not settled on an option yet, which means that you do not have an implementation yet.  If you do not have an implementation yet, you do not know whether the performance of this thing is going to be so crucial that you absolutely have to have the "most optimal" solution available.  So: pick a solution based exclusively on the merit of how easy it is to implement it, (abstracting it if necessary so that you can change it in the future,) and forget about it being "most optimal".  It probably won't matter.

Comment: @MikeNakis - I do have an implementation, I have already tried out PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream,  my overhead compared to just forwarding data from server1->server2 was more than 12% this seemed excessive, which is why I came up with more options. I already have abstracted out the implementations, except for 4. I could definitely implement and measure each of them - but I would like input from the community regarding which is a faster implementation.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at chronicle-queue https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue @peter-lawrey the author is very active here